# Webclient download EventArgs is not working on FTP

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, webclient

I would like to know why this piece of code is not working, it not throws any exception, the file is downloaded, just the events are not.

I've tried the same with the webclient upload EventArgs and them worked, but the Download EventArgs don't.

```
Private WithEvents client As New System.Net.WebClient()
ftp.DownloadFile(client, "/inputfile.ext", "c:\targetfile.ext")

Private Sub Client_DownloadProgress(ByVal sender As WebClient,
                                    ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) _
Handles client.DownloadProgressChanged
    MsgBox(e.ProgressPercentage & "%")

End Sub

Private Sub Client_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As WebClient, 
                                     ByVal e As DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles client.DownloadFileCompleted
    MsgBox(e.Result.ToString)
End Sub
```

the ftp object `DownloadFile` method is this:

```
Public Sub DownloadFile(ByRef DownloadClient As WebClient,
                        ByVal filepath As String,
                        ByVal localfilepath As String,
                        Optional ByVal Asynchronous As Boolean = False)

    If filepath.StartsWith("/") Then
        filepath = Me.host & filepath
    Else
        filepath = Me.host & "/" & filepath
    End If

    With DownloadClient
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.user, Me.pass)
        If Asynchronous Then
            .DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(filepath), localfilepath)
        Else
            .DownloadFile(New Uri(filepath), localfilepath)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you have to take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @K3rnel31 thanks for the documentation but is a little unclear (strange) for me, then that means what the events are only raised by the DownloadFileAsync webclient method? I see that yes, them are raised by that method, but this causes me two problems. 1. I don't understand why only an async can raise that events. 2. I'm getting this error at the eventhandlers  `can't convert type  'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' to type  'System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs'`. PS: Sorry about my english.

Comment: ok I've changed the method signature to `byval e as AsyncCompletedEventArgs` but then it throws an "object not set refence" exception when raising the download events, this stills unsolved.

Comment: @ElectroStudios ok hold on and let me help you on this ...

Comment: @K3rnel31 Finally I can handle the async download but what I need is to handle the process of a normal download, could you tell me if that is possibly or only can be handled the async downloads?

Comment: @K3rnel31 ok I was totally wrong maybe I need one more coffee tonight, ofcourse I'm thinking now that why I should need to raise events if the calling thread is blocked?, only async methods can raise them and thats the reason... or maybe not? this is getting me crazy

Comment: yes i think too and thats  why is Asynchronously an other option is for listening to events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click




    Dim w As New WebClient

    AddHandler w.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf downloadprogresschangedcallback
    AddHandler w.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf downloadfilecompletedcallback

    Dim address As String = "ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/ResKit/win2000/ADSizer.exe"

    Dim arg1 As System.Uri = New System.Uri(address)
    Dim arg2 As String = "C:\test\ADSizer.exe"

    w.DownloadFileAsync(arg1, arg2)


End Sub

Sub downloadprogresschangedcallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Debug.Print("Progress . . . ")
End Sub

Sub downloadfilecompletedcallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    Debug.Print("completed")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: No, that is totally incorrect, the `WithEvents` keyword on the variable declaration let the object raise events.

Comment: Yes it lets the object raise events, but in order for your handler to subscribe to them, you need to use addhandler to hook it up at runtime. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: with the usage of a withevents you don't need anymore to add manually the handle. `Why don't you just try it?` don't you should suppose things, I've tried it (even being sure that addhandler is not necessary), I've tried it and nothing happens. thanks anyways

Comment: Works for me. See also K3rnel31 's comment and link.

Comment: then could you add a code example in your answer to test it please?, it doesnt works for me

Comment: @ElektroStudios sorry for the delay been AFK. I've added a code sample to my answer.

Comment: @ElektroStudios yes of course you are right about WithEvents - I misremembered it. I knew there was a limitation to it, but it's that it will only work with Form/module level objects; it won't work (and throws a compile-time error) when the object is declared within the proc.

Comment: very generous, cheers. I have upvoted your answer too as it contains extra material.

Answer (score 1):

The unique reason why the events aren't raised (as said before by @K3rnel31 in the comments above) is that only the asynchronous webclient methods raises those events, then the only way to solve it is using the async methods, and really there is no need to raise events with the blocking methods, It just got me a little confused when trying to raise webclient events for first time, I did not thinked about what I was trying to do with the right logic.

> NOTE: And just to clarify, of course there is no need to addres the handler manually at runtime to any variable that
>   has been declared with the `withevents` keyword.

In the ftp class (which is just an helper class of ftpclient library http://netftp.codeplex.com/) I've wrote these methods:

```
''' <summary>
''' Uploads a file to FTP.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="UploadClient">Indicates the WebClient object to upload the file.</param>
''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp fle path.</param>
''' <param name="localfilepath">Specifies the local path where to save the downloaded file.</param>
''' <param name="Asynchronous">Indicates whether the download should be an Asynchronous operation, 
''' to raise WebClient events.</param>
Public Sub UploadFile(ByRef UploadClient As WebClient,
                      ByVal localfilepath As String,
                      Optional ByVal filepath As String = Nothing,
                      Optional ByVal Asynchronous As Boolean = False)

    If filepath Is Nothing Then
        filepath = Me.host & "/" & New IO.FileInfo(localfilepath).Name
    ElseIf filepath.StartsWith("/") Then
        filepath = Me.host & filepath
    Else
        filepath = Me.host & "/" & filepath
    End If

    With UploadClient
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.user, Me.pass)
        If Asynchronous Then
            .UploadFileAsync(New Uri(filepath), "STOR", localfilepath)
        Else
            .UploadFile(New Uri(filepath), "STOR", localfilepath)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Downloads a file from FTP.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="DownloadClient">Indicates the WebClient object to download the file.</param>
''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp fle path.</param>
''' <param name="localfilepath">Specifies the local path where to save the downloaded file.</param>
''' <param name="Asynchronous">Indicates whether the download should be an Asynchronous operation, 
''' to raise WebClient events.</param>
Public Sub DownloadFile(ByRef DownloadClient As WebClient,
                        ByVal filepath As String,
                        ByVal localfilepath As String,
                        Optional ByVal Asynchronous As Boolean = False)

    If filepath.StartsWith("/") Then
        filepath = Me.host & filepath
    Else
        filepath = Me.host & "/" & filepath
    End If

    MsgBox(filepath)
    With DownloadClient
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.user, Me.pass)
        If Asynchronous Then
            .DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(filepath), localfilepath)
        Else
            .DownloadFile(New Uri(filepath), localfilepath)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Then to handle the events (only for async methods ofcourse) I do this:

Notice that exist two `webclients` objects because a single webclient can't upload as async at the same time that it tries to download as asynchronous so it should throw an `E/S` exception then I use one client for uploads and other for downloads.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents UploadClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
    Private WithEvents DownloadClient As New System.Net.WebClient()

    Private ftp As New FTP("ftp site", "username", "password")

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        ftp.Connect()
        ftp.CreateDirectory("/DirectoryName", True)
        ftp.UploadFile(UploadClient, "C:\File.txt", "/DirectoryName/NewFile.txt", False)
        ftp.DownloadFile(DownloadClient, "/DirectoryName/NewFile.txt", "c:\DownloadedFile.txt", True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_UploadProgress(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.Net.UploadProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles UploadClient.UploadProgressChanged

        Label_Upload.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & "%"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_UploadCompleted(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.Net.UploadFileCompletedEventArgs) _
    Handles UploadClient.UploadFileCompleted

        Label_UploadCompleted.Text = e.Result.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_DownloadProgress(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles DownloadClient.DownloadProgressChanged

        Label_Download.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & "%"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_DownloadCompleted(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) _
     Handles DownloadClient.DownloadFileCompleted

        Label_DownloadCompleted.Text = "Done!"

    End Sub

End Class
```